# How to display number of rows in title of navigation bar? (iOS)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I tried to find the answer, but i didn't find any.
Please help me to display number of rows in title of uinavigationbar like in notes

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and code that you have tried.

Comment: How do you set the title displayed in the navigation bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as setting the title to something like

```
self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Notes (%i)", self.notes.count];
```

assuming that `notes` is the array where you store the `Note` elements.